# Can I use a Java based library in Robot Framework and only use pybot

Tags: java, python, robotframework

I installed `Python` and `Robot Framework`, I developed my test libraries with python and run my test cases with pybot..

Is there anyway to use Java based libraries in my test cases without installing and switching to `Jython`?

Or could I install `Jython`, but just use `Jython` as a way to import Java based libraries into my existing robot framework testcases?

My team has made quite a few Python based libraries but we have found some Java based libraries that offer functionality we're interested in using for our testing.

(I still want to run my cases with `"pybot"`, not `"jybot"`..)

Comment: From your question, it doesn't become apparent what your goal is. You want 'java library' but what is your reason for wanting it? Do you want to execute Java code from your python libraries? Do you want to interact with a Java application? Without this information it seems impossible to provide you with an answer...

Comment: Thank your comments, maybe I can make a little more clearly..    As I know there are 3 ways to use Robot Framework: 1. RF with Python; 2. RF with Jython; 3. RF with IronPython.  I use the 1st one(RF with Python), and based on it, we developed many test libraries with python and run our test case with "pybot".  And now, we find some Java libraries can provide some useful function in our testing, so we want to confirm whether it is possible to import a Java library to test case and do not change the way we use RF(We used to RF with Python, and still want to use it.)So could you give some advise?

Comment: Thanks Bryan Oakley's comments, it gives the clear info about this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across [Jpype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/) some time ago but I did not test it. It might be of some help.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a check with Jpype.

Comment: I checked instruction of Jpype, seems as a python module it provides a way to call Java library.